# IntelliJ/Kotlin upgrade causing "Incompatible types" error?

Tags: corda

I updated IntelliJ and kotlin to their latest version a couple days ago.  I *assume* it is one of these two actions that is causing my issue.  IntelliJ started highlighting errors on my QueryCriteria statements that it didn’t previously:

```
QueryCriteria myQueryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, singletonList(uuid), null, Vault.StateStatus.ALL);
```

Error:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria', required: 'net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria'
```

I have always used this syntax because I then pass myQueryCriteria into a Query:

```
Vault.Page<myContractState> page = mockNodeA.getServices().getVaultService().queryBy(myContractState.class, myQueryCriteria);
```

The error doesn’t stop my tests from running.    I’ve tried changing several settings but came to the realization I am better to ask people that are more familiar with java/kotlin/intelliJ/Corda before I make the problem worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick History:

- Originally installed IntelliJ 2018.3 to 2019.3 – no issues
- Upgraded to IntelliJ 2020.3.2 – no issues
- Updated to IntelliJ 2021.1 – error appeared

I ended up going back to IntelliJ 2020.3.3 to make the error stop

Docs clearly say:

*"Install the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. Corda supports IntelliJ IDEA versions 2017.x, 2018.x, 2019.x, and 2020.x; and Kotlin plugin version 1.2.71."*

…so when I updated to 2021.1 I was out of the recommended version.  When 2020.3.2 prompted me to update I didn’t realize it was going to take me to 2021.1 (my fault).

Background:
I am still really new to IntelliJ/Java but I tried everything I could think of the make the error go away and couldn’t fix it.

Kotlin Plugin:

- 2021.1 wouldn’t let me install the Kotlin Plugin 1.2.71 because it’s not supported.
- IntelliJ 2019.3 Kotlin Plugin 1.3.61-release-IJ2019.3-1 = no error
- IntelliJ 2020.3 Kotlin Plugin 203-1.4.10-release-IJ7717.8 = no error
- IntelliJ 2021.1 Kotlin Plugin 211-1.4.32-release-IJ6693.72 = error

I tried downgrading the Kotlin Plugin to an older version but it would always ignore the older plugin and stay with the new one.

I tried changing the Inspections but the error doesn’t seem to be coming from an inspection.

Changing the Kotlin compiler under Build, Execution, Deployment had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The current supported version of Kotlin is `1.2.71` (you can check out the [doc](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/cordapp-build-systems.html#choosing-your-corda-quasar-and-kotlin-versions) or the source code of Corda on github ([github.com/corda/corda/constant.properties](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os%2F4.7/constants.properties))).

I suggest you to downgrade the Kotlin version.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the plugin version?  I was only able to solve my issue by downgrading IntelliJ (see Accepted solution below).  I really didn't want to do that but I tried everything I could think of.  I appreciated your idea.

Comment: yes, plugin version. Sorry it was not clear. Voted your solution, useful analysis!

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a compiler error in Intellij IDEA. I have the same issue as you, using code downloaded from Corda's repository.

- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Ultimate Edition) = Error
- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Community Edition) = Error
- IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.4 (Ultimate Edition) = WORKS!

Comment: Good info.  I'll keep holding off on any upgrade (I am still using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3.)